# "using function-name" can only hide ordinary function?

Tags: c++

It seems that "using function-name" can only hide the ordinary function, but cannot hide the friend functions of the operand or the functions in the same namespace of the operand. Am I understanding this correctly?

example 1:

```
void swap(int)
{

}

void foo()
{
    using std::swap;
    int i=10,j=20;
    swap(i);  //compile error ,because  std::swap hidden void swap(int)
}
```

example 2:

```
class Cat {
    friend void swap(Cat&, Cat&);
};
void swap(Cat &lhs, Cat &rhs)
{
    cout<<"call cat friend swap"<<endl;
}

class Foo
{
    public:
        Cat h;
};

void swap(Foo &lhs, Foo &rhs)
{
    using std::swap;
    swap(lhs.h, rhs.h); //compile ok. will print out
                        //call cat friend swap
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's true.  `using` introduces a name at the local level, which hides names in enclosing namespaces.  But name search also uses argument-dependent lookup, which will still work (and might find some of the hidden names, too).  If you want to find `std::swap` and nothing else, then write `std::swap(i);`.

Comment: @BenVoigt that should be an (the) answer.

Comment: @TemplateRex: I was expecting this to get marked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your observation is correct.

`using` introduces a name at the local level, which hides names in enclosing namespaces. But name search also uses argument-dependent lookup, which will still work (and might find some of the hidden names, too). If you want to find `std::swap` and nothing else, then write `std::swap(i);`.